# UnsupportedError: cannot produce video at Transport.produce

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mediasoup

### As soon as I want to create a producer on client side I get this error: UnsupportedError: cannot produce video at Transport.produce

I created the device and I got the RtpCapabilities from the server. That all works fine. So why do I get this error as soon As I try to create a Producer on the client side ?

```
params = {
    encodings: [
      {
        rid: "r0",
        maxBitrate: 100000,
        scalabilityMode: "S1T3",
      },
      {
        rid: "r1",
        maxBitrate: 300000,
        scalabilityMode: "S1T3",
      },
      {
        rid: "r2",
        maxBitrate: 900000,
        scalabilityMode: "S1T3",
      },
    ],
    codecOptions: {
      videoGoogleStartBitrate: 1000,
    },
  };
const getVideo = () => {
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: true,
      })
      .then((stream) => {
        let video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
        video.srcObject = stream;
        video.play();
        console.log(stream);
        const track = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
        params = {
          track,
          ...params,
        };
      });
  };


const connectSendTransport = async () => {
    debugger;
    producer = await producerTransport.produce(params)

    producer.on("trackended", () => {
      console.log("track ended");
    });

    producer.on("transportclose", () => {
      console.log("transport ended");
    });
  };
  
const createSendTransport = () => {
    socket.emit("createWebRtcTransport", { sender: true }, ({ params }) => {
      if (params.error) {
        console.log(params.error);
        return;
      }
      console.log(params);

      debugger;
      producerTransport = device.createSendTransport(params);
      console.log(producerTransport);

      producerTransport.on(
        "connect",
        async ({ dtlsParameters }, callback, errback) => {
          try {
            await socket.emit("transport-connect", {
              // transportId: producerTransport.id,
              dtlsParameters: dtlsParameters,
            });

            callback();
          } catch (error) {
            errback(error);
          }
        }
      );

      producerTransport.on("produce", async (parameters, callback, errback) => {
        try {
          await socket.emit(
            "transport-producer",
            {
              // transportId: producerTransport.id,
              kind: parameters.kind,
              rtpParameters: parameters.rtpParameters,
              appData: parameters.appData,
            },
            ({ id }) => {
              callback({ id });
            }
          );
        } catch (error) {
          errback(error);
        }
      });
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

One needs to look at the full code to debug this. I had the same error.
I traced it back to - incorrect `rtpCapabilities` being passed-in during

```
            await device.load({
                routerRtpCapabilities: rtpCapabilities
            })
```

Comment: I got the same error, when I check in server side after creating router within the router.rtpCapabilities properties I can see the codecs array is empty.